# GUI stops working even though it's in its own thread and Thread.sleep() isn't called

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, thread-sleep

I have a problem. My GUI stops working when I press a JButton that links to a different class's method that uses

```
Thread.sleep();
```

I don't know why that is happening considering that I have my GUI in its own Thread. Please take a look at my code and tell me why that is happening!

Here is my GUI class:

```
package com.robot;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements Runnable {

//defines the panels
JPanel mainPanel;
JPanel labelPanel;
JPanel buttonPanel1;
JPanel buttonPanel2;
JPanel consolePanel;

//defines the label
JLabel title;

//defines the buttons
JButton runDemo;
JButton runLive;
JButton scan;
JButton findPatterns;
JButton cleanFolder;
JButton configureSettings;

//defines the console
JTextArea console;

//defines the line break
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

//start of the constructor method for GUI
public GUI() {

}

public void run() {
    //makes the program unable to be resized
            this.setResizable(false);

            //allows the user to close the program with the x button
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //sets the title of the program
            this.setTitle("ROBOT Alpha Alfred Version 3.0");

            //creates panels to hold the elements of the GUI
            mainPanel = new JPanel();
            labelPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel1 = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
            consolePanel = new JPanel();

            //creates label
            title = new JLabel("Robotically Operated Binary Options Trader");

            //creates buttons
            runDemo = new JButton("Run Demo");
            runLive = new JButton("Run Live");
            scan = new JButton("Scan Market");
            findPatterns = new JButton("Find Patterns");
            cleanFolder = new JButton("Clean Up Folder");
            configureSettings = new JButton("Configure Settings");

            //defines button listener objects
            ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();

            //adds buttons to button listeners
            runDemo.addActionListener(buttonListener);    
            runLive.addActionListener(buttonListener);
            scan.addActionListener(buttonListener);
            findPatterns.addActionListener(buttonListener);
            cleanFolder.addActionListener(buttonListener);
            configureSettings.addActionListener(buttonListener);

            //creates the console
            console = new JTextArea(6, 40);

            //sets the default text of the console
            console.setText("----------------------- ROBOT Console -----------------------" + newline);

            //makes the console unable to be edited
            console.setEditable(false);

            //sets the line wrapping of the console
            console.setLineWrap(true);
            console.setWrapStyleWord(true);

            //creates scroll bars
            JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(console);
            scrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            scrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

            //adds label to the label panel
            labelPanel.add(title);

            //adds buttons to the button panel
            buttonPanel1.add(runDemo);
            buttonPanel1.add(runLive);
            buttonPanel2.add(scan);
            buttonPanel2.add(findPatterns);
            buttonPanel2.add(cleanFolder);
            buttonPanel2.add(configureSettings);

            //adds the console to the console panel
            consolePanel.add(scrollBar);

            //adds panels to the main panel
            mainPanel.add(labelPanel);
            mainPanel.add(buttonPanel1);
            mainPanel.add(buttonPanel2);
            mainPanel.add(consolePanel);

            //adds the main panel to the frame
            this.add(mainPanel);

            //packs the GUI
            this.pack();

            //sizes the GUI
            this.setSize(600, 400);

            //centers the GUI
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            //sets the GUI to be visible
            this.setVisible(true);
}

public void add(String string) {
    console.append(string + newline);
}

//implement listeners
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == runDemo) {



        } else if(e.getSource() == runLive) {



        } else if(e.getSource() == scan) {

            try {
                ScanMarket.scanMarket();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if(e.getSource() == findPatterns) {

            try {
                FindPattern.findPattern("Images");
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if(e.getSource() == cleanFolder) {

            AddNeededFiles.addNeededFiles();

        } else if(e.getSource() == configureSettings) {



        }

    }

}

}
```

Here is where the GUI class is invoked:

```
//main method start
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {

    //opens up the GUI
    (new Thread(new GUI())).start();

    //possible methods
    //ScanMarket.scanMarket(); //scans market for data
    //FindPattern("Images"); //finds pattern among images in image folder labeled Images

}//end of main method
```

And here is a class's method that it links to that uses Thread.sleep();

```
package com.robot;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ScanMarket extends Main{

//define objects
RenameFile renameFile = new RenameFile();
IsGraphFull isGraphFull = new IsGraphFull();
NumberOfImagesInFolder numberOfImagesInFolder = new NumberOfImagesInFolder();
TakePicColumn takePicColumn = new TakePicColumn();
HasGraphCrashed hasGraphCrashed = new HasGraphCrashed();
RefreshPage refreshPage = new RefreshPage();

/*scanMarket is used to basically "scan" the market and will record captured images 
of all of the columns for many hours. This method will save the images in order, 
has crash protection and will run continuously for hours*/
public static void scanMarket() throws IOException, InterruptedException, AWTException {

    //tells number of images to scan
    float wantedImages = 700;

    //counts the number of images in the folder
    NumberOfImagesInFolder.numberOfImagesInFolder("Images");

    //creates the Number that is assigned to all images
    float nameCounter = NumberOfImagesInFolder.numberOfImagesInFolder;

    //saves the columns until we have 1000 images of different columns
    while (NumberOfImagesInFolder.numberOfImagesInFolder <= wantedImages) {

        //first check if the graph has crashed
        HasGraphCrashed.hasGraphCrashed();

        //if the graph has crashed then refresh the page
        if(HasGraphCrashed.hasGraphCrashed == true){

            //refresh the page
            RefreshPage.refreshPage();

            //alert the system it updated the page and the page is no longer down
            HasGraphCrashed.hasGraphCrashed=false;

        }

        //update the amount of images in the folder again
        NumberOfImagesInFolder.numberOfImagesInFolder("Images");

        //check if the graph is full 
        IsGraphFull.isGraphFull();

        //if the graph is full
        if (match == true) {

            //takes a picture of every single column
            TakePicColumn.takePicColumn();

            //sets up the 2 image locations for the first column

                //temporary first column image
                String file1 = imageLocation + "1" + end;

                //permanent first column image
                String file2 = imageLocation + "real" + nameCounter + end;

                //increases the value of the number assigned to each image so that the next image has a different value than the first image
                nameCounter++;

                //rename the temporary file to the permanent file name
                RenameFile.renameFile(file1, file2);

                //sets up the 2 image locations for the second column

                    //temporary second column image
                    file1 = imageLocation + "2" + end;

                    //permanent second column image
                    file2 = imageLocation + "real" + nameCounter + end;

                //increases the value of the number assigned to each image so that the next image has a different value than the second image
                nameCounter++;

                //rename the temporary file to the permanent file name
                RenameFile.renameFile(file1, file2);

                //sets up the 2 image locations for the third column

                    //temporary third column image
                    file1 = imageLocation + "3" + end;

                    //permanent third column image
                    file2 = imageLocation + "real" + nameCounter + end;

                //increases the value of the number assigned to each image so that the next image has a different value than the third image
                nameCounter++;

                //rename the temporary file to the permanent file name
                RenameFile.renameFile(file1, file2);

                //sets up the 2 image locations for the fourth column

                    //temporary fourth column image
                    file1 = imageLocation + "4" + end;

                    //permanent fourth column image
                    file2 = imageLocation + "real" + nameCounter + end;

                //increases the value of the number assigned to each image so that the next image has a different value than the fourth image
                nameCounter++;

                //rename the temporary file to the permanent file name
                RenameFile.renameFile(file1, file2);

                //sets up the 2 image locations for the fifth column

                    //temporary fifth column image
                    file1 = imageLocation + "5" + end;

                    //permanent fifth column image
                    file2 = imageLocation + "real" + nameCounter + end;

                    //increases the value of the number assigned to each image so that the next image has a different value than the fifth image
                    nameCounter++;

                //rename the temporary file to the permanent file name
                RenameFile.renameFile(file1, file2);

                //waits for graph to shift
                Thread.sleep(90000);

            }

            //create a temporary robot
            Robot test = new Robot();

            //move the mouse to the top left side of the screen to alert the person 
            //you can move the mouse for 90 seconds
            test.mouseMove(0,0);

            //give some time to let the user check what they need to check
            Thread.sleep(90000);

        }//end of if the graph is full statement

    }//end of capturing images

}
```

I don't know if I need to give that class its own Thread and then invoke that thread in my GUI class when I call the method via constructor or what! Please help me!

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` makes the current thread sleep. That is, the thread that executes that statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to push the operation off on to a different thread from the swing UI thread.

Swing has a special class to help with this - the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Answer (score 3):

Any Swing/ GUI read/write operation should run on the Event dispatch thread. You should use the 
[SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to ensure the GUI mutation/read runs on the Swing Thread.

Any operation you want to run in the background should be run on a separate thread.

You might want to use the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class to run background tasks. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 3):

When a button is pressed, the actionPerformed method will be called on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), which is responsible for handling events and drawing the GUI. Since you call a method that performs Thread.sleep() from actionPerformed(), you're still on the EDT, therefore preventing the EDT from redrawing the GUI.

You need to use a separate thread that runs the scanMarket() method.

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

1. You're calling `ScanMarket.scanMarket()`, a very long-running bit of code, on the Swing event thread by not putting it in a background thread.
2. You're calling the Swing GUI in a background thread when it should be queued on the Swing event thread.

solutions:

- Use a SwingWorker to create your background thread and make your long-running code run in its `doInBackground()` method.
- Make sure to queue your Swing code on the EDT, the Event Dispatch Thread, by passing a Runnable into the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` method.
- Read up on Swing's thread model and the problems that you're running into by reading the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial.